# Tiling of rectangular floor by $2\times 2, 1\times 4$ and $4\times 1$ tiles

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

A rectangular floor is covered by $2\times 2$ and $1\times 4$ tiles.

> One tile got smashed. There is a tile of the other kind available.
> Show that the floor cannot be covered by rearranging the tiles.

Today I was discussing that question with my friend and he told me that one can use coloring technique to solve this problem. By coloring he meant assigning to each cell of rectangular floor one of the four colors $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and he suggested to consider the following coloring such as: $$1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad \dots \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad $$
$$3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad \dots \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad $$
$$1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad \dots \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad $$
$$3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad \dots \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad $$
$$\vdots $$
$$1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad \dots \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad 1 \quad 2 \quad $$
$$3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad \dots \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad $$

In this example rectangular has even number of columns and rows but of course it could have size smth like $(2n+1)\times 2m$ or $2n\times (2m+1).$

This coloring has the property that each $2\times 2$ tile covers exactly $4$ different colors and $1\times4$ or $4\times 1$ covers eaxctly 2 colors.  Intuitively I understand it is not possible  to cover with rearrangement but I cannot prove it rigorously.

Can anyone explain to me please? Thank you so much for your attention!

**EDIT:** What does "Show that the floor cannot be covered by rearranging the tiles" mean? Is he asking to prove that the floor cannot be covered by replacing the smashed tile with the new tile and rearanging all of them?

Comment: @JMP, ohh good point! THank you! Did not notice that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to keep track of just a single color: say, the color $1$. The key difference between the tiles is that:

- A single $2 \times 2$ tile always covers a single tile of this color.
- A single $1 \times 4$ tile always covers $0$ or $2$ tiles of this color: an even number.

Therefore:

- If there is an odd number of this color, an odd number of $2 \times 2$ tiles must be used when we cover the entire floor.
- If there is an even number of this color, an even number of $2 \times 2$ tiles must be used when we cover the entire floor.

Swapping out a $2\times 2$ tile for a $1\times 4$ tile, or vice versa, changes the parity of $2\times 2$ tiles (from even to odd, or vice versa). Since we started with the correct parity to cover the floor, we now have the incorrect parity, and we cannot do it.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the last paragraph. What do you mean by "parity of $2\times 2$ tiles"?

Comment: @PlayGame The "parity" of something is whether it's even or odd.

Comment: After some thoughts I've realized that you probably meant the following:  1) If the number of 1's is odd, then the number of 2by2 tiles is odd also. If 2by2 is replaced with 1by4, then the number of 2by2 tiles become even (since odd-1=even) but it means that number of 1's is even. The reamining cases are the same. Is that correct?

Comment: Or more precisely, in the scenario you described, the number of $2 \times 2$ tiles becomes even, the number of $1$s on the floor stays odd (since we didn't change the shape of the floor) and that means we can't cover the floor anymore (since even$\ne$odd).

Comment: My reasoning was correct, right?

Comment: I think that I got your point! Now it is clear to me. I accept your answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello! Excuse me I was wondering can you take a look at this question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500021/extremal-property-of-tur%c3%a1n-graph-t-n-r

Answer (score 2):

Using your numbering, consider the squares numbered $1$. Every $2\times 2$ covers exactly one $1$, which is an odd number of $1$'s, while every $1\times 4$ or $4\times 1$ covers either zero or two squares labeled $1$, which is always even. Therefore, in every tiling of a rectangle, the parity of the number of $1$'s must match the parity of the number of $2\times 2$ tiles. However, if you smash one tile and replace it with the other, then you would change the parity of the number of $2\times 2$ squares.

For example, consider a $5\times 4$ rectangle. Using the numbering below, the number of $1$'s is even. We see that we can tile this rectangle using either $0$, $2$, or $4$ squares. However, in any of those tilings, if you broke one of the squares and replaced it with a skinny tile, or if you broke a skinny tile and replaced it with a square, the number of squares would be odd. Since there are six $1$'s in the rectangle, an odd number of squares and several skinny tiles would always cover an odd number of ones, so there would be at least one $1$ leftover, so you could not tile the board with the modified tile set.

```
1 2 1 2 1
3 4 3 4 3    # of 1's = 6
1 2 1 2 1
3 4 3 4 3

0 squares     2 squares     4 squares
A B C D E     A A C D E     A A C C E
A B C D E     A A C D E     A A C C E
A B C D E     B B C D E     B B D D E 
A B C D E     B B C D E     B B D D E
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a correct tiling of your floor with a set of tiles. You will have covered $\frac{nm}{4}$ ones, twos, threes and fours.

If one tile is replaced, say a $2\times 2$, you will expose a $1,2,3,4$. The new tile,  $4\times 1$, can only cover two of these twice, and so there is no covering available.

Comment: "you can color only 2 colors?" What does that mean?

Comment: You keep all the original tiles except for the broken one, which is swapped, when you re-tile. If a $2\times 2$ is broken, it is replaced by a $4\times 1$, which won't reach all the colours on your floor.

Comment: I am really confused and do not understand your reasoning. Can you be a more specific?

Comment: @PlayGame; I've updated my answer, is it any clearer?

Comment: If $2\times 2$ is broken then which tile will replace it? It is not clear from the context of the problems. What if $1\times 4$ or $4\times 1$ is broken?

Comment: A 4by1 is the same tile as a 1by4. Whichever type of tile breaks, the other type is used to replace it.

Comment: So we replace $2\times 2$ by $1\times 4$ and vice versa. Right? It was not obvious from the problem!