# A rectangular board was covered without overlapping by $1×4$ and $2×2$ polyminos . Then the polyminos were removed from the board but one $2×2$ was

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

A rectangular board was covered without overlapping by $1×4$ and $2×2$ polyminos . Then the polyminos were removed from the board but one $2×2$ was lost . Instead, another $1×4$ polymino was provided . Prove that now the board cannot be covered by the polyminos without overlapping.

This is a question from Mathematical Circles by Dimitri Fomin, Sergey Genkin and IIa Itenberg.

The solution given is as follows:

> Let us consider the coloring using $4$ colors . Then each $2×2$ title contains exactly one box of color $1$ and each $1×4$ tile contains none or two boxes of color $1$. Therefore,  the parity of the number $2×2$ polyminoes coincides with the parity of the number of boxes of color $1$. This prove the statement:after the parity of the number if $2×2$ polyminoes changed(when one has lost) we cannot cover the same board without overlapping .

However, I am not getting the idea of the solution . How can they conclude that the parity of the number of $1$ colored boxes is same as that of the number of $2×2$polyminos.  How can we be sure that in the original arrangement when the polymino was not lost there were no $1×4$ polyminos on a $1$ colored square. I am not getting it... also there is a duplicate link suggested ...however the detailed one there ...i mean the solution which is probably one of the most detailed one or maybe the only one is as follows:

> It is enough to keep track of just a single color: say, the color 1. The key difference between the tiles is that:
> A single 2×2 tile always covers a single tile of this color.
> A single 1×4 tile always covers 0 or 2 tiles of this color: an even number.
> Therefore:
> If there is an odd number of this color, an odd number of 2×2 tiles must be used when we cover the entire floor.
> If there is an even number of this color, an even number of 2×2 tiles must be used when we cover the entire floor.
> Swapping out a 2×2 tile for a 1×4 tile, or vice versa, changes the parity of 2×2 tiles (from even to odd, or vice versa). Since we started with the correct parity to cover the floor, we now have the incorrect parity, and we cannot do it.

I am not getting it. What if the parity of number of $1's$ is even to begin with ...now after one $2×2 $ square is lost ...no of $2×2 $ polyminos is odd ...but $1×4$ polyminos can cover an even number of $1's$ so there shouldn't be any problem....so the solution looks a bit off ...I dont quite get it...Also then a $2×2$ polymino may be extra ....Furthermore I am asking about a certain proof  ....The user in that post asked about the solutions...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tiling of rectangular floor by $2\times 2, 1\times 4$ and $4\times 1$ tiles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432929/tiling-of-rectangular-floor-by-2-times-2-1-times-4-and-4-times-1-tiles)

Comment: @JMP Thanks ! but no that doesnt answer my question at all ..please check the post...The link in that question wants a different thing..while I posted for a specific reason as explained by me in the post...they are entirely both different causes...

Comment: You just need to think about the given solution more, or [Misha's excellent answer]( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432949). The situation where no $1\times 4$ are on a $1$ tile is accounted for; zero is even, just like two is even.

Comment: I advise you to do this exercise to help learn the intuition. Draw rectangles of various sizes, tile them with squares and 1x4's in various ways, and for each, count the parity of the number of $1$ tiles, and the parity of the number of squares. You will see they always agree.